# How can i modify this bootstrap code?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found a code from

http://usebootstrap.com/theme/facebook

But in this code, I want to make 'Home icon' never be collapsed at any browser size.

**CODE:**

```
         <div class="navbar navbar-blue navbar-static-top">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a href="http://usebootstrap.com/theme/facebook" class="navbar-brand logo">b</a>
            </div>
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li>
               ###▽▽▽ I want this icon remain on the navbar, not in collapsed dropdown menu
                <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
               ###△△△ I want this icon remain on the navbar, not in collapsed dropdown menu
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

**Bootply:** https://www.bootply.com/lEfd188zDg

I tried to move `<a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>` to after `<a href="http://usebootstrap.com/theme/facebook" class="navbar-brand logo">b</a>`, but it looks very ugly.

I want that 'Home icon' is still seen in smaller browser size, being looks nicely not ugly. How can i modify well?

**EDIT**

**Pic:**

This simplified code is a little different from above code that i posted firstly.

**Simplified code:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="box">
<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
<div class="column col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="main">
<!-- top nav -->
<div class="navbar navbar-blue navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
      </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="">More</a></li>
          <li><a href="">More</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
<!-- /top nav -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

original result is like:

[image]

and in narrow browser,

[image]

But purpose result is like:

[image]

Would give me the way how to make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just updated your `HTML` code and added `CSS`. Just replace it with yours. Please Only tap nav.

```
<style>

.heading-icons li{ 
padding: 9px 10px; 
margin-top: 8px; 
margin-right: 15px; 
}

</style>
<div class="navbar navbar-blue navbar-static-top">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                    <ul class="list-inline heading-icons">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-header col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <!-- /top nav -->
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but i edited my post, sorry. would you read my edit?

Comment: add a live link. I can have look

Comment: Here is google drive link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3-MNdQEiu0odlVuYTFTUmRlV2s          And I'm sorry i missed there is other asset files. But i cant understand asset files contents Because i'm newbie at css or bootstrap. Would you help me?

Comment: You can look the code from facebook.html in linked file

Comment: Sure, I like to help people.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156952/discussion-between-sodhi-saab-and-touchingtwist).